# SSRS report won't launch if multiple parameters in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I am trying to pass parameters to my SSRS report from an .NET application.

I have 3 parameters to pass: instanceID, EL and OL.

In my code-behind, I have codes as below:

```
        string params = Session["instanceID"].ToString() + "&EL=unhide&OL=unhide";
        string script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> ";
        script += "OpenLink1(" + params + ");";
        script += "</SCRIPT>";
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("ClientScript", script);
```

My javascript code is as below:

```
function OpenLink1(params ) {
    var str = "http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<path>%2f<report name>%2<report name>&rs:Command=Render&instanceID=" + params;

    window.open(str, "List", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600");
    return false;
}
```

No matter what I do, the report just won't launch (pop up).

The EL and OL parameters are supposed to hide tables in the SSRS report.

e.g. `=IIF(Parameters!EL.Value = "hide", false, true)`

If I remove these 2 parameters from the report and take away the parameter in the URL in code behind, the SSRS report launches without any problems.

What confuses me is that if I directly enter the URL in the browser, the report works fine - which lead me to believe that something to do with my coding and passing the parameters is wrong?

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the javascript that you're generating in your code behind.  You need to put single quotes around the params variable when you're creating your function call in the generated javascript.

```
    script += "OpenLink1('" + params + "');";
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH. I feel so silly...tried every single trick I could think of to fix it..thank man!